# Oracle ADF or Java

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-adf

I am using ADF `autoSuggestBehavior` to show list of values.
But the problem is it is showing only the values that start with the typed character, I want to show all the results that contain that specific character.

Example - If there is a list of country and you type U, it will suggest for countries starting with U. But what I want is to show all the countries that contains the letter U it may be the starting character or ending character.

Please suggest any solution either in JAVA or ADF.

Comment: We won't give out solutions to you. What have you tried?

Comment: Also express which version of ADF you are using? 10g, 11g, 12c with the exact minor versions, Examples: `11.1.1.2`, `11.1.1.4`, `11.1.1.6`, ... . Also I suggest you to escape using ADF if it is not too late.

Comment: Its 11g, and 11.1.1.6 version.I

Comment: Can you add the code that you used? The ADF tags and the implementation of suggestItems method.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the ViewObjectImpl class of the ViewObject on the basis of whome LOV is made and paste the following code.

applyViewCriteria(ViewCriteria, boolean) is invoked in case of autosuggest and overriding this method will solve your problem

```
@Override
    public void applyViewCriteria(ViewCriteria viewCriteria, boolean b) {
        super.applyViewCriteria(supressStartsWithClauseForLov(viewCriteria), b);
    }

    public ViewCriteria supressStartsWithClauseForLov(ViewCriteria vc){
        if(vc != null && vc.getName().contains("__lov__filterlist__vcr__")){
            ViewCriteriaRow currentRow = (ViewCriteriaRow)vc.getCurrentRow();
            if(currentRow != null){
                List criteriaItems = currentRow.getCriteriaItems();
                for(int i = 0 ; i < criteriaItems.size() ; i++){
                    ViewCriteriaItem object = (ViewCriteriaItem)criteriaItems.get(i);
                    if(object != null){
                        System.out.println("Operator is : "+object.getOperator());
                        if("STARTSWITH".equals(object.getOperator())){
                            object.setOperator("CONTAINS");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return vc;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry,I am new to ADF,Thats why I am not getting where to get ViewObjectImpl  class.I have a implemented this by Binding a list to suggestedItems,like :suggestedItems="#{inOutMailBean.getSuggestedItems1}"

Comment: and this list is loaded while jspx page is loading .So if you could guide me from here,It will be very helpful And Thank you for your quick response

Comment: You have not populated suggestedItems from ADF binding ?
how you have applied lov?
If you are using viewObject to apply lov only then you can override this method

Comment: No I have not populated suggestedItems from ADF binding.I have simply get the list from DB doing a ejb call in init() method and binded that LIST to suggestedItems .

Comment: Is there any way to solve this with out viewObject?Or else If you can tell me how to implement autosuggest with viewObject ,I will try.

Comment: I have never tried this without viewObject , you can create a viewObject with query that has lov values and then apply lov using that viewObject
Check this link - http://www.awasthiashish.com/2014/06/adf-basics-implementing-auto-suggest.html